# Existence of matrix $C$ such that $f(A)=tr(AC)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

Let $f: M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)\to \mathbb R$ a functional. Prove that there exists a unique square matrix $C$ such that $f(A)=tr(AC)$ for all $A\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$

I´ve been trying to solve this problem but unfortunately I don´t know where to start. I would really appreciate if you can give me some hints or suggestions

Comment: Is that functional linear?

Comment: If the functional is continuous and linear, the Riesz representation theorem assures the unique existence of matrix $C$ by considering the norm $\|A\| = \sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(AA^t)}$.

Comment: There must be restrictions: $f(0) = \text{tr}(0)=0$

Comment: Would you know how to do this for an $f:\Bbb R^{n^2}\to \Bbb R$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Note that $\operatorname{trace}(AB^T)$ is just the "dot product" of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint!. I´ll try to solve it